# Wildcard meaning any but not empty in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following list of files in a folder:

- vim
- viminfo
- vimrc
- vimrcpg
- vimrcsh

I want to list all files starting with vim but not vim itself. If I use vim*, the result include vim. Is there any wildcard that produce the desired result ?

Comment: How about `vim?*`?

Comment: vim?* looks good as I did not expect two wildcards would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a folder called '/home/user' with the following files inside:

```
vim
viminfo
vimrc
vimrcpg
vimrcsh
```

Then:

```
ls -A1 /home/user | grep -E '^vim(?<!$)'
```

will print:

```
viminfo
vimrc
vimrcpg
vimrcsh
```

`ls-A1` means print folder content names only `A` one-by-line `1`

`grep -E '^vim(?<!$)'` means print lines starting `^` with `vim` and not `?<!` ending with newline `$` after match

If you want to list files only:

```
find /home/user -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n' | grep -E '^vim(?<!$)'
```